# Hibernate EntityManager with getSessionFactoryGetCurrentSession()

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I changed my application to work with Hibernate EntityManager (from Hibernate session), 
 
but i have some old codes (i can not change those codes) that used in below code:

`getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession()` .

i have bean of sessionFactory so the code above supposed to work but in runtime i have
`HibernateException("No Session found for current thread")` ,even the code above was executed in transaction block.

FYI: I checked the transaction resources (in debug mode) and with key EntityManagerFactory, session exist but not under SessionFactory key

Comment: please post the code related to transaction management (portion of xml app context, sample code with @Transactional annotation or xml declaration of transactional methods if you use that)

Comment: i wrote in my question **even the code above was executed in transaction block.** so the exception occur even code with @Transactional annotation or xml declaration of transactional methods

Comment: Yes ... but did you check that the transaction actually start ? -you can check that simply by enabling the appropriate logger- (it's possible to have an @Transactional doing absolutely nothing if something is badly configure somewhere else.)

Comment: I checked the transactuon resources (in debug mode) and with key EntityManagerFactory, session exist  but not under SessionFactory key!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I suggest you to do this (seems hacky, but with legacy code, it's sometimes required)

This solution use Spring [TransactionSynchronizationManager](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/transaction/support/TransactionSynchronizationManager.html) and Hibernate 4, but can be adapted to other Hibernate version.

Here is the idea: using a custom implementation of [CurrentSessionContext](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/javadocs/org/hibernate/context/spi/CurrentSessionContext.html) in your SessionFactoryBean, and this custom implementation will search in the transactional resources for the entity manager of the current transaction; when it is found simply calling the code posted by IIla to get the hibernate Session.

To do it :

**1.Define the property `hibernate.current_session_context_class` in hibernateProperties:**

```
<bean id="sessionFactory"
      class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    ...
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            ...
            <prop key="hibernate.current_session_context_class">
                com.example.jpa.HibernateSessionInEntityManager
            </prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<!-- for completness : here are the other relevant beans -->

<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter"/>
    </property>
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.example.jpa.validator"/>
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager"
      class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
</bean>
```

**2.Implement your custom CurrentSessionContext : HibernateSessionInEntityManager.java**

```
import org.hibernate.HibernateException;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.context.spi.CurrentSessionContext;
import org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerImpl;
import org.hibernate.engine.spi.SessionFactoryImplementor;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerHolder;
import org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionSynchronizationManager;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import java.util.Map;

public class HibernateSessionInEntityManager implements CurrentSessionContext {

    public HibernateSessionInEntityManager() {
    }

    public HibernateSessionInEntityManager(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
    }

    public HibernateSessionInEntityManager(SessionFactoryImplementor sessionFactory) {
    }

    public Session currentSession() throws HibernateException {
        Map<Object, Object> resourceMap = TransactionSynchronizationManager.getResourceMap();
        for(Object v:resourceMap.values()){
            if(v instanceof EntityManagerHolder){
                return getSessionFromEM(((EntityManagerHolder)v).getEntityManager());
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    private static Session getSessionFromEM(final EntityManager entityManager)
    {
        final Object emDelegate = entityManager.getDelegate();
        if (emDelegate instanceof EntityManagerImpl)
        {
            return ((EntityManagerImpl) emDelegate).getSession();
        }
        else if (emDelegate instanceof Session)
        {
            return (Session) emDelegate;
        }
        throw new HibernateException("No Session found");
    }
 }
```

Note all those constructors: Hibernate-4 needs the one with `SessionFactoryImplementor` and I think Hibernate-3 needs the one with `SessionFactory`. (The no-args constructor is probably not required)

**3.Here a simple test case to validate that it works**

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath:ApplicationContext.xml" })
public class HibernateSessionInEntityManagerTest {

    @Autowired
    public SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @Test
    @Transactional
    public void testGetHibernateSession(){
        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        Assert.assertNotNull(session);
    }
}
```

I hope it will help. (BTW: nice question)

Important remark: if you have multiple EntityManagerFactoryBean be carrefull to choose the good one when looking into the transactionnal resources. (i.e. for instance look at the persistenceUnitName of the associated entityManagerFactory)

Comment: @nir did you try it ? is it running for you ?

Answer (score 0):

Shorter implementation of the "getSessionFromEM" method:

```
    private static Session getSessionFromEM(final EntityManager entityManager){
    return entityManager.unwrap(Session.class);
}
```