# Access SessionFactory from Spring Boot Application

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot

I am trying to get access to the Hibernate session factory but am getting the following error at the line mentioned.

```
No CurrentSessionContext configured!
```

code

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class GenericSearchImpl implements GenericSearch {

    @Autowired
    private EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;

    @Override
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public <T> List<T> search(final Class<T> type, final String[] criteriaList, final int page, final int perPage) {
        Session session = getSession();
        ...
    }

    public Session getSession() {
        final HibernateEntityManagerFactory emFactory = (HibernateEntityManagerFactory) entityManagerFactory;
        final SessionFactory sessionFactory = emFactory.getSessionFactory(); 
        return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession(); //ERROR No CurrentSessionContext configured!

          //This worked but I understand it to be BAD as spring should be managing open sessions.
          //        try {
          //            return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
          //        } catch (Exception e) {
          //            return sessionFactory.openSession();
          //        }
    }

    ...

}
```

Any idea why?

Comment: JPA doesn't use the `CurrentSessionContext` class. Configuring it should solve your problem. Simply add the configuration for the current session context and let it point to the `org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.SpringSessionContext` class. However why are you trying this? WHy not use plain JPA?

Comment: @M.Deinum I am doing this to support some legacy code that is using Hibernate Criteria.  It will eventually be converted over to JPA.  The rest of the application is using spring-data-jpa, I only need the Hibernate SessionFactory temporarily until it can be rewritten.  Will a hybrid approach like this work?  Can you give an example of configuring CurrentSessionContext as a spring bean in java config?

Comment: Is [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26667910/no-currentsessioncontext-configured?answertab=active#tab-top) what you mean?

Comment: Yes it is (and as that is basically the same question, marked this one as duplicate).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18759978/hibernate-entitymanager-with-getsessionfactorygetcurrentsession. Please refer this. Shows you how exactly this can be done.

Comment: @M.Deinum I followed that tutorial but still get `No CurrentSessionContext configured!`

Comment: Just did an update on that, it is missing a crucial configuration property.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In property file,

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.current_session_context_class=org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.SpringSessionContext
```

in configuration class

```
@Bean
public HibernateJpaSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
    return new HibernateJpaSessionFactoryBean();
}
```

Then you can autowire

```
@Autowired
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;
```

We do this as Spring boot doesn't auto configure hibernate sessinoFactory.

**Update:** As of **Spring 4.3.12 and Hibernate 5.2**, [above Hibernate API solution is depreciated](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/jpa/vendor/HibernateJpaSessionFactoryBean.html) in favor of generic JPA API solution EntityManagerFactory.

```
Session session = entityManager.unwrap(Session.class);
```

[Here](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/quickstart/en-US/html/hibernate-gsg-tutorial-jpa.html) is some detailed example doc with examples on EntityManagerFactory.

Comment: This is deprecated now.

Answer (score 6):

You can access SessionFactory with entityManagerFactory unwrap method instead of HibernateJpaSessionFactoryBean

```
SessionFactory sessionFactory = entityManagerFactory.unwrap(SessionFactory.class);
```

HibernateJpaSessionFactoryBean is deprecated in Spring Boot 1.5.8